# Get list of category for magento using oauth api

Tags: php, api, magento, oauth

I want to get category list for magento using `oAuth` magento api.I want to make sure that is is not for a particular product but for all categories.

Comment: The first step would be Googling `magento api category list`. Does this not help?: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalogCategory.html

Comment: we want to get category list using magento rest api but this is soap api.

Comment: Ah, I see. According to http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction_to_rest_api#rest_resources this doesn't seem possible

Comment: you know how we create this type of new rest api? if you know then please forward important link.

Comment: nope, I don't know Magento that well... but you could check out the source code. It may be possible to build this without too much trouble. It's so Magento specific though that it might be best to ask at their support forum

Comment: Follow my answer on this question that create new magento rest api to get categories list and also guide about how to create new rest api. [Extending the magento Rest Api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037773/create-new-magento-rest-api-to-get-category-list-in-magento/15757760#15757760). Hope it helps to all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox you can download [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/) and you can try it on your browser.

I never use REST API to get list of category. But [this](http://www.aschroder.com/2012/04/introduction-to-the-magento-rest-apis-with-oauth-in-version-1-7/) link might be helpful for you.
For this case They install `oAuth` on Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're working with OAuth, but I was just working on something that might help - this will get you all the categories via SOAP API:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://admin.aboyd.vp-dev.com/magento/api/soap?wsdl', array('trace' => 1, "connection_timeout" => 120));

// Can be added in Magento-Admin -> Web Services with role set to admin
// log in to API
try {
    $sessionId = $client->login('username', 'api-password');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
    die();
}

// get all categories
$allCats = $client->call($sessionId, 'catalog_category.tree');
```

The crux is the catalog_category.tree call, see http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.tree.html