# Display categories and their subcategories in Magento using REST API

Tags: php, api, magento, rest

Can anyone help me display categories and their subcategories using the REST API?

I have tried this url:

```
http://localhost/magento/api/rest/products/:productId/categories
```

But it displays category *ID* instead of what I'd need, i.e. something like this:

```
http://localhost/magento/api/rest/categories
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my case website/api/rest/products?limit=2 return 404 error, i am using rest, any idea about this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
/api/rest/products/:productId/categories
```

This should retrieve a list of categories assigned to a specific product. Unfortunately, this won't lead you to the elegant solution you deserve.

If you want a list of categories *you may have to use the soap api* to retrieve the categories using the [catalog_categories.tree method](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.tree.html). I realize "use some other api" is the worst kind of answer but, it is what Magento currently offers.

The alternative is to extend the stock api with your own restful patchwork, but, life is short.

If you really want to do something like that then, this other Stack Overflow question will help get you started:
[Create new magento Rest api to get category list in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037773/create-new-magento-rest-api-to-get-category-list-in-magento?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

There is indeed still nothing to be found either in [Magento 1.x API guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Products/product_categories.html) either in the code.

You can clearly see in the folder structure of the `Mage_Catalog` module that the model representing categories are still only sub models of the product, so it's main goal is still "only" to be able to know in which categories a specific product is linked to.

[image: Magento Folder Structure for REST API Model]

And the code of this category model being of class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Category_Rest` doesn't look like anything as changed from the previous answer, sadly (around line 61 in the latest version 1.9.2.4) :

```
protected function _retrieveCollection()
{
    $return = array();

    foreach ($this->_getCategoryIds() as $categoryId) {
        $return[] = array('category_id' => $categoryId);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

And I am unsure if Magento is still going to put any effort in REST API on the version 1.x of the framework.

Although there seems to be hope in [Magento 2.x API list](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html) listing those available methods :

> DELETE /V1/categories/:categoryId
>   GET    /V1/categories/:categoryId
>   POST   /V1/categories
>   GET    /V1/categories
>   PUT    /V1/categories/:id
>   PUT    /V1/categories/:categoryId/move

Also the code offers possibilities to get the categories tree.
See [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/CategoryManagementInterface.php#L23) and [there](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/webapi.xml#L341).

So it is definitely something possible under Magento 2.x