# How to create Categories webservice api in magento and in android app

Tags: web-services, magento, magento-1.8

I want to know how to create the Webservice in magento 1.8.0 which fetch all the categories name of the store and then I need to show on my Android application.

So please advice.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can crate your own api for category.list  with use of below link you can sure create your api

[Create new magento Rest api to get category list in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037773/create-new-magento-rest-api-to-get-category-list-in-magento)

Also if you want to create your own function to fetch category you can also create your own function like below

```
function get_categories(){

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
$tree = $category->getTreeModel(); 
$tree->load();
$ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds(); 
$arr = array();
if ($ids){ 
foreach ($ids as $id){ 
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
$cat->load($id);
$arr[$id] = $cat->getName();
} 
}

return $arr;

}


  $arr =  get_categories();
 $arr = array_flip($arr);
 echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: hope my answer will useful to you. pls dont forget to accept if it is >