# Rest Webservice in magento 1.8.0

Tags: android, web-services, magento, rest

I want to create a REST webservice in magento to fetch all categories and product from the website. But as I am new into the magento, so I just wondering how I can achieve this job.

So could you please advise me step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Magento already has a REST web-service that allows you to retrieve products (and sales and customers).
Check the System->Webservices menu, the submenus that start with `REST`.
See some [documentation here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html)
You can try to extend that to categories following the same standards. The REST API is defined in the module `Mage_Api2`.
I also recommend [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15757760/2047249). It can give you a start.