# Magento Rest-Api Category List

Tags: list, rest, magento, categories

I would like to create a Category List Extension for the Magento Rest Api.

There is a thread posted at stackoverflow:

[Create new magento Rest api to get category list in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037773/create-new-magento-rest-api-to-get-category-list-in-magento)

But it shows only a small incomplete piece of code which is not working.
It seems that the developer just copied a short snippet from the following extension by Marko Andreini:

https://github.com/marcoandreini/magento-extendedrestapi

But I can't get it to work with Magento 1.9.

I alway get an 403 -access denied when calling /magento/api/rest/categories

I would be very pleased if someone has an idea what's the problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working for me:

```
                    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
                    $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();

                    $result = array();


                    if (count($_categories) > 0) {

                        $i = 0;
                        foreach ($_categories as $_category) {

                            $katId = $_category->getId();

                                $result[$i]['katId'] = $katId;
                                $result[$i]['url'] = $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category);
                                $result[$i]['katName'] = $_category->getName();
                                $result[$i]['katSubs'] = null;

                                $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
                                $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();

                                $j = 0;
                                if (count($_subcategories) > 0) {

                                    foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory) {

                                        $subKatId = $_subcategory->getId();
                                        $subKatName = $_subcategory->getName();

                                        if ($subKatId && $subKatName && $subKatName != "") {

                                            $result[$i]['katSubs'][$j]['parentKatId'] = $katId;
                                            $result[$i]['katSubs'][$j]['subKatId'] = $subKatId;
                                            $result[$i]['katSubs'][$j]['url'] =  $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory);
                                            $result[$i]['katSubs'][$j]['subKatName'] = $subKatName;

                                            $j++;
                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Responding to Jet Miller post above, 403 access means "forbidden".
Make sure the authentication works properly, set the roles and attributes correctly.
Other alternative would be creating "**guest**" privilege under **etc/api2.xml**

```
<privileges>
   <admin>
      <retrieve>1</retrieve>
   </admin>
   <guest>
      <retrieve>1</retrieve>
   </guest> 
</privileges>
```

Then create another folder **Model/Api2/Category/Rest/Guest/**

Copy the V1.php inside Model/Api2/Category/Rest/Admin/ to newly created guest folder.
Don't forget to change class name to:
[namespace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Api2_Category_Rest_**Guest**_V1

and i guess you'll good to go