# Extend magento rest api to get category listing

Tags: rest, magento

I have created an extended service using [Create new magento Rest api to get category list in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037773/create-new-magento-rest-api-to-get-category-list-in-magento) , Now don't know what will be the url to hit that service.

Answer (score 1):

$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$allCategories = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'category.tree'); // Get all categories.

this code will ussfull to call the api(SOAP), run this form root.

Comment: You are right, this is correct in case of soap, but i need to do it using REST api.

Answer (score 0):

$oauthClient= new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
$oauthClient->enableDebug();

Call rest using this code